JavaScript iterate over array of elements and return a single element based on max px size
I have several elements on a page that are positioned absolutely.
I am trying to iterate over them and find the one which has the highest top value.
I have tried the following toggling off 1 and 2 respectively):
const elems = document.querySelectorAll('.index-posts > li');

const newElems = [...elems].filter(item => Math.max(parseInt(item?.style?.top))); // returns the entire array
const newElems = Math.max([...elems].map(item => parseInt(item?.style?.top?.split('px')[0]))); // returns NaN

By my reckoning the first version should be working but maybe my implementation of Math.max is not quite right. Although perhaps it returns each item because it is the max height per item.
I also found this which I used to create the second var
Finding the max value of a property in an array of objects


const elems = document.querySelectorAll('.index-posts > li');

// const newElems = [...elems].filter(item => Math.max(parseInt(item?.style?.top)));

const newElems = Math.max([...elems].map(item => parseInt(item.style.top.split('px')[0])));

console.log(newElems);
<ul class="index-posts row"><li id="affirmation" style="top: 3px; left: 0%;">
            <a href="affirmation" class="post-trigger">
                <p class="item-name">affirmation</p><p>
                </p><p></p></a><p class="npf_link" data-npf="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;link&quot;,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;https://vimeo.com/153949952?share=copy&quot;,&quot;display_url&quot;:&quot;https://vimeo.com/153949952?share=copy&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Affirmation (2016)&quot;,&quot;description&quot;:&quot;Affirmation (2016) uses footage from the 1923 Buster Keaton film Three Ages as the basis for a guided meditation in vulnerability. Keaton wa&quot;,&quot;site_name&quot;:&quot;Vimeo&quot;,&quot;poster&quot;:[{&quot;media_key&quot;:&quot;cd78c9656df6b9381417c980464efff7:86fa2ab3c65a5863-70&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;image/webp&quot;,&quot;width&quot;:1920,&quot;height&quot;:1080}]}"><a href="affirmation" class="post-trigger"></a><a href="https://vimeo.com/153949952?share=copy" target="_blank">Affirmation (2016)</a></p><p>Affirmation <br>2016<br>Single channel video</p><p>Affirmation uses footage from the 1923 Buster Keaton film Three Ages as the basis for a guided meditation in vulnerability. Keaton was badly injured shooting this portion of the film and chose to keep the jarring moment of impact in the finished comedy.</p><p></p>
            
        </li><li id="effort" style="top: 261px;">
            <a href="effort" class="post-trigger">
                <p class="item-name">effort</p><p>
                </p><p></p><div class="npf_row"><figure class="tmblr-full" data-orig-height="1000" data-orig-width="713"><img src="https://64.media.tumblr.com/d0d03da92f0ec700bf9aae4d6912dd38/b1f2ac6c91328716-f2/s640x960/9eb6114bae89b82c69822fed1f6f4ad34335049e.jpg" data-orig-height="1000" data-orig-width="713" srcset="https://64.media.tumblr.com/d0d03da92f0ec700bf9aae4d6912dd38/b1f2ac6c91328716-f2/s75x75_c1/2cc38731a6a28c2f0c733a297cd0930a09bc9df7.jpg 75w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/d0d03da92f0ec700bf9aae4d6912dd38/b1f2ac6c91328716-f2/s100x200/ae323c424555c9db2e1b3d3c261a8e34e8887ea2.jpg 100w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/d0d03da92f0ec700bf9aae4d6912dd38/b1f2ac6c91328716-f2/s250x400/2230190d1b796e0bb2c3d06a4d3340bcd82ba996.jpg 250w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/d0d03da92f0ec700bf9aae4d6912dd38/b1f2ac6c91328716-f2/s400x600/08a6c1efdff0e7d27ac13700f41bdcb5daf294ea.jpg 400w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/d0d03da92f0ec700bf9aae4d6912dd38/b1f2ac6c91328716-f2/s500x750/d9b6655f9c05f336b79414f2b9c4ad233e64caa4.jpg 500w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/d0d03da92f0ec700bf9aae4d6912dd38/b1f2ac6c91328716-f2/s540x810/9f04cbd2451438359fdf209cbb3d63010b9a98dd.jpg 540w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/d0d03da92f0ec700bf9aae4d6912dd38/b1f2ac6c91328716-f2/s640x960/9eb6114bae89b82c69822fed1f6f4ad34335049e.jpg 640w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/d0d03da92f0ec700bf9aae4d6912dd38/b1f2ac6c91328716-f2/s1280x1920/45e28d03b9f19b8c11bd5cfb4e156fadb1c55cc2.jpg 713w" sizes="(max-width: 713px) 100vw, 713px"></figure></div><p>Effort! We Cried<br>2015<br>Graphite on paper</p><p></p>
            </a>
        </li><li id="gods_and_monsters" style="top: 693px; left: 64%;">
            <a href="gods_and_monsters" class="post-trigger">
                <p class="item-name">gods_and_monsters</p><p>
                </p><p></p><div class="npf_row"><figure class="tmblr-full" data-orig-height="1127" data-orig-width="1600"><img src="https://64.media.tumblr.com/4b399cc6c60cedadcc68ab1fa071ebd3/a2e7db5f1c359aa0-ee/s640x960/9dd2426e8f33676d1bf6e6ce36e4b8821deabff9.jpg" data-orig-height="1127" data-orig-width="1600" srcset="https://64.media.tumblr.com/4b399cc6c60cedadcc68ab1fa071ebd3/a2e7db5f1c359aa0-ee/s75x75_c1/82270247b35222ceb18cab29951708b72c94744a.jpg 75w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/4b399cc6c60cedadcc68ab1fa071ebd3/a2e7db5f1c359aa0-ee/s100x200/d2fd855eb165cae8f704d984ee6d6a2e69625067.jpg 100w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/4b399cc6c60cedadcc68ab1fa071ebd3/a2e7db5f1c359aa0-ee/s250x400/4f2301e431b81a3664f0d7a9ff13a7d7a724147b.jpg 250w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/4b399cc6c60cedadcc68ab1fa071ebd3/a2e7db5f1c359aa0-ee/s400x600/3e92e57e70820b607151770f4bf5ebfb80cc1084.jpg 400w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/4b399cc6c60cedadcc68ab1fa071ebd3/a2e7db5f1c359aa0-ee/s500x750/1173c49cff5b2cbf363bebb688cdb1454335f178.jpg 500w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/4b399cc6c60cedadcc68ab1fa071ebd3/a2e7db5f1c359aa0-ee/s540x810/641315a2992d144de36e7b635f5d4078407f2d86.jpg 540w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/4b399cc6c60cedadcc68ab1fa071ebd3/a2e7db5f1c359aa0-ee/s640x960/9dd2426e8f33676d1bf6e6ce36e4b8821deabff9.jpg 640w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/4b399cc6c60cedadcc68ab1fa071ebd3/a2e7db5f1c359aa0-ee/s1280x1920/7a49988e09cacb2a34d8d2cd1deee65d318d326a.jpg 1280w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/4b399cc6c60cedadcc68ab1fa071ebd3/a2e7db5f1c359aa0-ee/s2048x3072/1241a81bc082dedfac48d65312e83d5560437851.jpg 1600w" sizes="(max-width: 1280px) 100vw, 1280px"></figure></div><div class="npf_row"><figure class="tmblr-full" data-orig-height="1133" data-orig-width="1600"><img src="https://64.media.tumblr.com/40e63fdb3b123969b7e6a6db269ae90f/a2e7db5f1c359aa0-d4/s640x960/ab06b023935cdd4952a76175818ae829bb44d117.jpg" data-orig-height="1133" data-orig-width="1600" srcset="https://64.media.tumblr.com/40e63fdb3b123969b7e6a6db269ae90f/a2e7db5f1c359aa0-d4/s75x75_c1/19b8d86b15b1573198c51386fd1564c130d395f2.jpg 75w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/40e63fdb3b123969b7e6a6db269ae90f/a2e7db5f1c359aa0-d4/s100x200/ae5f9a4ddcee4ed3241eb52d41eccf8d1601cd37.jpg 100w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/40e63fdb3b123969b7e6a6db269ae90f/a2e7db5f1c359aa0-d4/s250x400/ed3b92d3e926ea3074e9586da2cb2d4fa4db0fdf.jpg 250w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/40e63fdb3b123969b7e6a6db269ae90f/a2e7db5f1c359aa0-d4/s400x600/e1fe9708e8f136671961bee70c6c55f712a71bb3.jpg 400w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/40e63fdb3b123969b7e6a6db269ae90f/a2e7db5f1c359aa0-d4/s500x750/5b1d130c6d65e06c03af8809679e3d0c3dc582af.jpg 500w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/40e63fdb3b123969b7e6a6db269ae90f/a2e7db5f1c359aa0-d4/s540x810/6d3ac9afbc7a616a2f1b70d324728a9b99ff7c0f.jpg 540w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/40e63fdb3b123969b7e6a6db269ae90f/a2e7db5f1c359aa0-d4/s640x960/ab06b023935cdd4952a76175818ae829bb44d117.jpg 640w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/40e63fdb3b123969b7e6a6db269ae90f/a2e7db5f1c359aa0-d4/s1280x1920/5850982fab64960722b13b44de2372836deabe83.jpg 1280w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/40e63fdb3b123969b7e6a6db269ae90f/a2e7db5f1c359aa0-d4/s2048x3072/2dd480b82c5ebc16067e80a5beee41d845f7d6af.jpg 1600w" sizes="(max-width: 1280px) 100vw, 1280px"></figure></div><p>Gods and Monsters <br>2019<br>A series of five hand-lettered postcards sent to the authorities in the artist’s life.</p><p>Recipients: UK Home Office, Arts Council England, U.S. Embassy London, Northamptonshire County Council, the artist’s parents</p><p></p>
            </a>
        </li><li id="icebergs" style="top: 1351px; height: 323px; width: 23%; left: 18%;">
            <a href="icebergs" class="post-trigger">
                <p class="item-name">icebergs</p><p>
                </p><p></p><div class="npf_row"><figure class="tmblr-full" data-orig-height="2744" data-orig-width="2768"><img src="https://64.media.tumblr.com/4736c31d438c972627c101383a5e87b4/c53eef444214311f-4b/s640x960/6bd0bd6a4978e953ba7049090ca983550188a816.jpg" data-orig-height="2744" data-orig-width="2768" srcset="https://64.media.tumblr.com/4736c31d438c972627c101383a5e87b4/c53eef444214311f-4b/s75x75_c1/14ae47d022ae43d026221e38e2f3f0fb0abf8971.jpg 75w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/4736c31d438c972627c101383a5e87b4/c53eef444214311f-4b/s100x200/beb98adf13c0a47a8ce5c3fc77568fff1f581753.jpg 100w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/4736c31d438c972627c101383a5e87b4/c53eef444214311f-4b/s250x400/041fef40aba89b1c98999384f040d7acb55c5b75.jpg 250w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/4736c31d438c972627c101383a5e87b4/c53eef444214311f-4b/s400x600/63d640ad3f8c1c88c25f5d8c735a8c394b22a5da.jpg 400w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/4736c31d438c972627c101383a5e87b4/c53eef444214311f-4b/s500x750/c440119d5ebd89f347ba1ee1bb316937252c84ee.jpg 500w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/4736c31d438c972627c101383a5e87b4/c53eef444214311f-4b/s540x810/97489f044a1e170ed6f02dcedba98e99a085bd2b.jpg 540w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/4736c31d438c972627c101383a5e87b4/c53eef444214311f-4b/s640x960/6bd0bd6a4978e953ba7049090ca983550188a816.jpg 640w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/4736c31d438c972627c101383a5e87b4/c53eef444214311f-4b/s1280x1920/f8a8b1864ed64ca44bb7102a678e4f0ac082c701.jpg 1280w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/4736c31d438c972627c101383a5e87b4/c53eef444214311f-4b/s2048x3072/fd919ad6408a099544f7a4b3c3622c5eadea655d.jpg 2048w" sizes="(max-width: 1280px) 100vw, 1280px"></figure></div><p>I only paint icebergs <br>2014-current <br>Acrylic on canvas</p><p></p>
            </a>
        </li><li id="nameless_befores" style="top: 351px; height: 247px;">
            <a href="nameless_befores" class="post-trigger">
                <p class="item-name">nameless_befores</p><p>
                </p><p></p><div class="npf_row"><figure class="tmblr-full" data-orig-height="3419" data-orig-width="2230"><img src="https://64.media.tumblr.com/7a0b55d3164969c5d7ed2a5e1ad558c2/ecdcd2893cf24923-8c/s640x960/06873ae01989f545e42f6230d307a510d07cd5a9.jpg" data-orig-height="3419" data-orig-width="2230" srcset="https://64.media.tumblr.com/7a0b55d3164969c5d7ed2a5e1ad558c2/ecdcd2893cf24923-8c/s75x75_c1/7308505c10b07da0ef4acdcb3b229eea2551ac7b.jpg 75w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/7a0b55d3164969c5d7ed2a5e1ad558c2/ecdcd2893cf24923-8c/s100x200/389b54834be0f04a1811474cd45aec9c23251834.jpg 100w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/7a0b55d3164969c5d7ed2a5e1ad558c2/ecdcd2893cf24923-8c/s250x400/bd248b00d0c76e442ec66ae04616f4c1e97cee38.jpg 250w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/7a0b55d3164969c5d7ed2a5e1ad558c2/ecdcd2893cf24923-8c/s400x600/6cf86776dd1b6a9b8eecfd0adff76af55fd821ed.jpg 391w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/7a0b55d3164969c5d7ed2a5e1ad558c2/ecdcd2893cf24923-8c/s500x750/204d84a576e75531474a0fa42025c5721fa7cd27.jpg 489w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/7a0b55d3164969c5d7ed2a5e1ad558c2/ecdcd2893cf24923-8c/s540x810/1e68a30f17da789984fae65001d59c1a4c0f27e3.jpg 528w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/7a0b55d3164969c5d7ed2a5e1ad558c2/ecdcd2893cf24923-8c/s640x960/06873ae01989f545e42f6230d307a510d07cd5a9.jpg 626w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/7a0b55d3164969c5d7ed2a5e1ad558c2/ecdcd2893cf24923-8c/s1280x1920/536d38ca09ed3ee4ae48f68d367b5a7175f62904.jpg 1252w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/7a0b55d3164969c5d7ed2a5e1ad558c2/ecdcd2893cf24923-8c/s2048x3072/b69bbe7884a099a9d28a36e4aef989b918872747.jpg 2004w" sizes="(max-width: 1280px) 100vw, 1280px"></figure></div><p>Nameless Befores<br>2019-2020<br>Collage, graphite and pen on paper</p><p></p>
            </a>
        </li><li id="not_funny" style="top: 273px;">
            <a href="not_funny" class="post-trigger">
                <p class="item-name">not_funny</p><p>
                </p><p></p><div class="npf_row"><figure class="tmblr-full" data-orig-height="2714" data-orig-width="2745"><img src="https://64.media.tumblr.com/a39784308f8ad45b90881f4b30f0fe94/196841d0b63faa59-e9/s640x960/49397d1a483a7266dbec0d04fb10673c77796a14.jpg" data-orig-height="2714" data-orig-width="2745" srcset="https://64.media.tumblr.com/a39784308f8ad45b90881f4b30f0fe94/196841d0b63faa59-e9/s75x75_c1/507989a2dff769f0a66e07f8f687a1848cca5e24.jpg 75w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/a39784308f8ad45b90881f4b30f0fe94/196841d0b63faa59-e9/s100x200/d69ef5ddc45101bbf97478c08cdb5dd80516db21.jpg 100w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/a39784308f8ad45b90881f4b30f0fe94/196841d0b63faa59-e9/s250x400/a526294f20e0876d044ba565bf39f1d1c8b84675.jpg 250w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/a39784308f8ad45b90881f4b30f0fe94/196841d0b63faa59-e9/s400x600/d15c9b620362625981ec73f2f06bdd59af7dfcf2.jpg 400w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/a39784308f8ad45b90881f4b30f0fe94/196841d0b63faa59-e9/s500x750/116e73900acc93b4a792b6fcfd21470eb27724c0.jpg 500w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/a39784308f8ad45b90881f4b30f0fe94/196841d0b63faa59-e9/s540x810/b63d1a5814a77d9642b0ab95c518dddcee6fbcaf.jpg 540w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/a39784308f8ad45b90881f4b30f0fe94/196841d0b63faa59-e9/s640x960/49397d1a483a7266dbec0d04fb10673c77796a14.jpg 640w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/a39784308f8ad45b90881f4b30f0fe94/196841d0b63faa59-e9/s1280x1920/df4cad5016b8043c726dff1a8b0097d2d0fd4f0d.jpg 1280w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/a39784308f8ad45b90881f4b30f0fe94/196841d0b63faa59-e9/s2048x3072/bbd67c52186c4f2909bae8755f1c1b9e3b513fce.jpg 2048w" sizes="(max-width: 1280px) 100vw, 1280px"></figure></div><p>I’M NOT FUNNY ANYMORE<br>2022-2023<br>Coloured pencil and marker on paper</p><p></p>
            </a>
        </li><li id="photogram" style="top: 683px;">
            <a href="photogram" class="post-trigger">
                <p class="item-name">photogram</p><p>
                </p><p></p><div class="npf_row"><figure class="tmblr-full" data-orig-height="6797" data-orig-width="8389"><img src="https://64.media.tumblr.com/8b285a90b66b30f8c648f82535ec4cda/0ca99e56b3c437b7-30/s640x960/75784a6bfcbd4961f8ab174bc6f9ca224af4dbca.jpg" data-orig-height="6797" data-orig-width="8389" srcset="https://64.media.tumblr.com/8b285a90b66b30f8c648f82535ec4cda/0ca99e56b3c437b7-30/s75x75_c1/d477768c521c536669974af46e641a246374e773.jpg 75w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/8b285a90b66b30f8c648f82535ec4cda/0ca99e56b3c437b7-30/s100x200/8d0c2fdf1c40ba99b563a76053336c442ef88deb.jpg 100w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/8b285a90b66b30f8c648f82535ec4cda/0ca99e56b3c437b7-30/s250x400/5fbee7381136b7bb1a12dfa7f58d39b90325b02d.jpg 250w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/8b285a90b66b30f8c648f82535ec4cda/0ca99e56b3c437b7-30/s400x600/14099ca7545b18bf5dd81fdbf47e19ddf004e5f7.jpg 400w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/8b285a90b66b30f8c648f82535ec4cda/0ca99e56b3c437b7-30/s500x750/1b1073b976f22c9648d8498cb1ab00fabf241a98.jpg 500w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/8b285a90b66b30f8c648f82535ec4cda/0ca99e56b3c437b7-30/s540x810/9d1de80bcd46f14eafa6b78ca616f90378d7f85a.jpg 540w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/8b285a90b66b30f8c648f82535ec4cda/0ca99e56b3c437b7-30/s640x960/75784a6bfcbd4961f8ab174bc6f9ca224af4dbca.jpg 640w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/8b285a90b66b30f8c648f82535ec4cda/0ca99e56b3c437b7-30/s1280x1920/44fbd64f8f5a68479a092290d3bebf419e0bc14d.jpg 1280w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/8b285a90b66b30f8c648f82535ec4cda/0ca99e56b3c437b7-30/s2048x3072/a330b0d05ac886e1ef6c909aea4700cf3972b68b.jpg 2048w" sizes="(max-width: 1280px) 100vw, 1280px"></figure></div><p>Instant colour photogram<br>2021</p><p></p>
            </a>
        </li><li id="referendum" style="top: 611px; height: 446px; left: 14%;">
            <a href="referendum" class="post-trigger">
                <p class="item-name">referendum</p><p>
                </p><p></p><figure class="tmblr-full tmblr-embed" data-provider="vimeo" data-url="https://vimeo.com/221735806?share=copy" data-orig-width="540" data-orig-height="304"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/221735806?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;app_id=122963" width="540" height="304" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture; clipboard-write" title="Video clip depicting interactive online work Referendum (Tell Me How Do You Feel)"></iframe></figure><p>Referendum (Tell Me How Do You Feel)<br>2016-2017<br>Interactive online work</p><p>Referendum (Tell Me How Do You Feel) was an interactive online sister piece to the physical installation of the same name, requiring the viewer to vote on the artist’s citizenship. The online iteration reduced the practical and legal arguments for citizenship to a flood of visuals concerning the country of the artist’s birth and the country the artist now calls home, along with a quote from Rebecca Solnit’s book Wanderlust: A History of Walking.</p></a><p><a href="referendum" class="post-trigger">This work was commissioned by Fermynwoods Contemporary Art for its </a><a href="https://www.a-n.co.uk/news/online-exhibition-sees-us-artists-respond-to-trump-presidency/">Open 7: Can You Hear Me?</a></p><p></p>
            
        </li><li id="shield" style="top: 625px; height: 458px;">
            <a href="shield" class="post-trigger">
                <p class="item-name">shield</p><p>
                </p><p></p><div class="npf_row"><figure class="tmblr-full" data-orig-height="4032" data-orig-width="2640"><img src="https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s640x960/d85c9c2f7f4ff41832f548cc2cac89905e6fe01b.jpg" data-orig-height="4032" data-orig-width="2640" srcset="https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s75x75_c1/eb876d72933b6138eeba73ca59499c3809975b61.jpg 75w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s100x200/21f86af6b60e44ba7d90090281dc1a1461494805.jpg 100w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s250x400/eba73e6b36bf95f9473e9276592794923583d9de.jpg 250w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s400x600/f202a41604edd3e6cfeee2f9457620bbc87accff.jpg 393w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s500x750/3def886512d22590bb2b72396d147cb8007ccd46.jpg 491w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s540x810/d83eb22083d9dafb4feae95e2f4a2ca0553e0ae8.jpg 530w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s640x960/d85c9c2f7f4ff41832f548cc2cac89905e6fe01b.jpg 629w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s1280x1920/1c03d83fdad14df8334745de77595cd9d2215ce7.jpg 1257w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s2048x3072/ee6e6bf1448c6304fbf6cbed93062b9ca520baf3.jpg 2011w" sizes="(max-width: 1280px) 100vw, 1280px"></figure></div><p>Shield<br>2018<br>Wax, display case, light</p><p>Shield is a meditation on masculinity and power. The tiles are wax casts of the substantial belt buckle once belonging to the artist’s grandfather, who was a Chicago Police Sergeant investigated in the 1970s as part of a ring of police shaking down motorists for payoffs. While eventually granted immunity from prosecution by the state, he was indicted, along with two fellow policemen, for perjury by a grand jury for lying about his involvement.</p><p></p>
            </a>
        </li><li id="tappatappatappa" style="top: 352px; height: 249px;">
            <a href="tappatappatappa" class="post-trigger">
                <p class="item-name">tappatappatappa</p><p>
                </p><p></p><div class="npf_row"><figure class="tmblr-full" data-orig-height="570" data-orig-width="570"><img src="https://64.media.tumblr.com/e941cce115f54b050dd2fdae5366580b/6fad0e4f24c9057d-1f/s640x960/42553538aedce243e572d658fdb3e3a805e22d05.jpg" data-orig-height="570" data-orig-width="570" srcset="https://64.media.tumblr.com/e941cce115f54b050dd2fdae5366580b/6fad0e4f24c9057d-1f/s75x75_c1/f3f6e1ed40aeb78963cb1da70f1513d4c82ad0c5.jpg 75w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/e941cce115f54b050dd2fdae5366580b/6fad0e4f24c9057d-1f/s100x200/748ebcf728a133b679f467b72feb3029bab26394.jpg 100w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/e941cce115f54b050dd2fdae5366580b/6fad0e4f24c9057d-1f/s250x400/ecc972107a967547438aa98b954d349ae74463dc.jpg 250w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/e941cce115f54b050dd2fdae5366580b/6fad0e4f24c9057d-1f/s400x600/f254547b7528a35626354375ffaf3ad33dca3b69.jpg 400w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/e941cce115f54b050dd2fdae5366580b/6fad0e4f24c9057d-1f/s500x750/0803bac2b9ceae3a2be4d98974e110928688b3cd.jpg 500w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/e941cce115f54b050dd2fdae5366580b/6fad0e4f24c9057d-1f/s540x810/2658da93ea7df6208e5b77ab0a8c15c2e05183ab.jpg 540w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/e941cce115f54b050dd2fdae5366580b/6fad0e4f24c9057d-1f/s640x960/42553538aedce243e572d658fdb3e3a805e22d05.jpg 570w" sizes="(max-width: 570px) 100vw, 570px"></figure></div><p>TAPPA TAPPA TAPPA<br>2012-2018<br>Series of five zines</p></a><p><a href="tappatappatappa" class="post-trigger"></a><a href="https://www.tappazine.com/">TAPPA TAPPA TAPPA</a> was a collaboration between writer Amy Pettifer and artist Jessica Harby.</p><p></p>
            
        </li><li id="the_thing" style="top: 485px; left: 31%;">
            <a href="the_thing" class="post-trigger">
                <p class="item-name">the_thing</p><p>
                </p><p></p><div class="npf_row"><figure class="tmblr-full" data-orig-height="1728" data-orig-width="2592"><img src="https://64.media.tumblr.com/df886ab0308a396250010d9022f4146a/5c1228652df16585-5d/s640x960/f5f5e93cd13d9e3afeb405a2ec221aae406affe8.jpg" data-orig-height="1728" data-orig-width="2592" srcset="https://64.media.tumblr.com/df886ab0308a396250010d9022f4146a/5c1228652df16585-5d/s75x75_c1/6644c7c9ce264760c5f82a1964a8628e952040d8.jpg 75w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/df886ab0308a396250010d9022f4146a/5c1228652df16585-5d/s100x200/ba913b19ba04c397bbba8d92aafeb74af4e629ab.jpg 100w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/df886ab0308a396250010d9022f4146a/5c1228652df16585-5d/s250x400/f0e9373a98434a971bca275dda5d171f0f42afe3.jpg 250w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/df886ab0308a396250010d9022f4146a/5c1228652df16585-5d/s400x600/a33687ea9733cacda6aea68c073a62dabcb98fbc.jpg 400w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/df886ab0308a396250010d9022f4146a/5c1228652df16585-5d/s500x750/af0cd2660d8448fd4901d4f56263ed1b0c2e597f.jpg 500w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/df886ab0308a396250010d9022f4146a/5c1228652df16585-5d/s540x810/1726cb1c8f70f83678ae2c84393657024fc05e4c.jpg 540w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/df886ab0308a396250010d9022f4146a/5c1228652df16585-5d/s640x960/f5f5e93cd13d9e3afeb405a2ec221aae406affe8.jpg 640w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/df886ab0308a396250010d9022f4146a/5c1228652df16585-5d/s1280x1920/93d5d5b9d7f12d636105d585c3c2b18b87405994.jpg 1280w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/df886ab0308a396250010d9022f4146a/5c1228652df16585-5d/s2048x3072/4f397f37f1e6839699631552da450b3d1b9ab6c4.jpg 2048w" sizes="(max-width: 1280px) 100vw, 1280px"></figure></div><p>The Thing or The Oh Noeux Tapestry<br>2017<br>Embroidery on Canvas</p><p>The Thing or The Oh Noeux Tapestry is a fourteen-metre long work of endurance embroidery began 1 January 2017 and completed 31 December 2017, documenting the news and the process of consuming it.</p><p></p>
            </a>
        </li><li id="tiny_malevolent" style="top: -12px; height: 342px; width: 41%; left: 47%;">
            <a href="tiny_malevolent" class="post-trigger">
                <p class="item-name">tiny_malevolent</p><p>
                </p><p></p><div class="npf_row"><figure class="tmblr-full" data-orig-height="2123" data-orig-width="2875"><img src="https://64.media.tumblr.com/3e08839dca1e50d94c5f6aaf5d9ed5db/c53be9c758c4c913-52/s640x960/a97988384b36163b04f0cb5e3077880eeb4e41d7.jpg" data-orig-height="2123" data-orig-width="2875" srcset="https://64.media.tumblr.com/3e08839dca1e50d94c5f6aaf5d9ed5db/c53be9c758c4c913-52/s75x75_c1/b697df9126fd9af3cd59caaebb8b057f101f9f43.jpg 75w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/3e08839dca1e50d94c5f6aaf5d9ed5db/c53be9c758c4c913-52/s100x200/5e3ef7ee5db72e68ff449147e812f13c5ce0c5d3.jpg 100w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/3e08839dca1e50d94c5f6aaf5d9ed5db/c53be9c758c4c913-52/s250x400/ef8d4d1465b0b21a34960b781b1f145ee6f8404a.jpg 250w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/3e08839dca1e50d94c5f6aaf5d9ed5db/c53be9c758c4c913-52/s400x600/df6c546703bceedd9a55c2c53d94d5f3b8cbdab0.jpg 400w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/3e08839dca1e50d94c5f6aaf5d9ed5db/c53be9c758c4c913-52/s500x750/4aff1e7a88cc3a0bc7ea80d50e864ef62b8aa636.jpg 500w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/3e08839dca1e50d94c5f6aaf5d9ed5db/c53be9c758c4c913-52/s540x810/a65b32cd5e2472410c10ac43cadcb0497cd85d7f.jpg 540w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/3e08839dca1e50d94c5f6aaf5d9ed5db/c53be9c758c4c913-52/s640x960/a97988384b36163b04f0cb5e3077880eeb4e41d7.jpg 640w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/3e08839dca1e50d94c5f6aaf5d9ed5db/c53be9c758c4c913-52/s1280x1920/94e9654f3e6bde6d0490e3546786d434362947b7.jpg 1280w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/3e08839dca1e50d94c5f6aaf5d9ed5db/c53be9c758c4c913-52/s2048x3072/14ae3d38534b6379aebbaf11d6c201a61d86de3a.jpg 2048w" sizes="(max-width: 1280px) 100vw, 1280px"></figure></div><p>Tiny Malevolent Women<br>2018-2019<br>Charcoal and graphite on paper</p><p>A series of drawings depicting:<br>The Mourners<br>The Climber<br>The Rat King<br>The Quorum<br>The Rat King<br>The Seamstresses<br>The Devil’s Triangle<br>The Watchful Eye Which Has Not and Will Not Rest<br>The Again<br>The Again<br>The Again<br>The Again<br>The Again</p><p></p>
            </a>
        </li><li id="very_realistic" style="top: 2px; height: 248px; left: 14%;">
            <a href="very_realistic" class="post-trigger">
                <p class="item-name">very_realistic</p><p>
                </p><p></p><figure class="tmblr-full tmblr-embed" data-provider="vimeo" data-url="https://vimeo.com/544276930?share=copy" data-orig-width="540" data-orig-height="304"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/544276930?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;app_id=122963" width="540" height="304" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture; clipboard-write" title="Very Realistic (2021)"></iframe></figure><p>Very Realistic<br>2021<br>Single channel video </p><p>In The Great Muppet Caper (1981), reporters Kermit, Fozzie, and Gonzo travel to London to investigate a jewel theft. Whilst riding in a red double-decker bus over the Thames, the following exchange takes place:</p><p>Fozzie: Wow, look at the scenery!<br>Gonzo: It’s very realistic.</p><p>It is 2021, we have lived/are living through a collective trauma and during a car ride the landscape turned to a throbbing reality and we secretly begged to be let back inside.</p><p></p>
            </a>
        </li></ul>



There is also a JSFIDDLE here: https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/382yunhq/ where I have tried more verbose methods.
If anyone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Math.max expects every number to be a separate argument, not a single array. Math.max(...[...elems].map(item => parseInt(item.style.top.split('px')[0])));

Thank you. This returns the number, I actually want the whole item, which is why I was using filter initially. Or trying to.

To find the item having maximum top, you can reduce the array and check items one by one and return the item having bigger top each time.
const biggestItem = Array.from(elems).reduce((a, b) => {
    return parseInt(b.style.top) > parseInt(a.style.top) ? b : a;
});


Thank you! I have never quite got my head arround reduce. Much appreciated.
